# Calendar selection based on working days using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, c#-4.0

I have to selected the based dates for days calculation based on Working days (eg: 5.0, 5.5, 6.0).
when i select based on 5.5 days, I would like to calculate automatically.
Kindly help me to solve this issues.

```
    private void SelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs obj)
            {
               if(Settings.WorkingDay == "5.0")
                {
                   // Code is working fine
                }
               else if(Settings.WorkingDay == "5.5")
                {
                    startDate = SelectedRange.StartDate.Date;
                    endDate = SelectedRange.EndDate.Date;
                    startDate.AddDays(1);
                    int days = 0;
                    for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
                    {
                        if (startDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                        {
                            days++;
                        }
                        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
                    }
                    if(startDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && endDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                    {
                        Quantity = (days) - (Convert.ToDecimal(0.5));
                    }
                    else if(startDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                    {
                        Quantity = (days);
                    }
                    Debug.WriteLine(Quantity.ToString());
                }
               else if(Settings.WorkingDay == "6.0")
                {
                   // Code is working fine
                }
            }
```

Comment: what is the issue you are trying to solve?  What is wrong with the code you've posted?

Comment: For example: 5.5 working days, which means saturday as Half day. When I select the from date and to date in calendar or datepicker. I would like to calculate the days (if its with saturday taken as 0.5 days)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
double qty = 0.0;

for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
   if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
   {
      // do nothing
   } 
   elseif (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
   {
      qty += 0.5;
   } 
   else 
   {  
      qty ++ 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: “Not working” is not a helpful description.  What inputs are you using?  What is the expected result and the actual result?